# While cloning ohmyzh in the terminal, it says, "file not found." Why?

Tags: git, terminal, macos-sierra

[image: screen shot of error]

Which is:

```
 <machine>:~ techmick$ $ sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://...)"
 bash: $: command not found
```

There seems to be an error.

Not sure why. What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have copied the `$` in front of the command.

It is a shell prompt maker, and should not be part of it.

You should only copy and execute:

```
sh -c ...
```

Not:

```
$ sh -c ...
```